# Condition to apply between two timestamp column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have start_datetime and end_datetime. Both are timestamp column. While selecting I need to check if end_datetime is not null and end_datetime >= start_datettime then take end_datetime else no need to print.

I am using Redshift.

```
CASE 
 WHEN PRICEROW.price_end_time IS NOT NULL OR PRICEROW.price_end_time!='' 
      THEN PRICEROW.price_end_time 
END AS SOFTMARK_END_DATETIME
```

I am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is something like this:

```
(CASE WHEN PRICEROW.price_end_time > PRICEROW.price_start_time  
      THEN PRICEROW.price_end_time 
 END) AS SOFTMARK_END_DATETIME
```

The `NULL` check is implicit in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query.

```
CASE 
 WHEN nvl(PRICEROW.price_end_time,'') !='' AND PRICEROW.price_end_time > PRICEROW.price_start_time
      THEN PRICEROW.price_end_time 
END AS SOFTMARK_END_DATETIME
```